# MOSS Site Collection Documents - Restricting special characters in a filename

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, filenames, sharepoint-documents

I am trying to block users from entering square brackets ([]) or other charcters to a filename while uploading a document.

Is there a way to block this in SharePoint Central Administration or is there settings that I can change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to intercept the EventReciever during synchronous call (ItemAdding and ItemUpdating method) and cancel the event.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create an event receiver or a workflow to do this.

Have a look at the first sample [in this post](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/sharepoint-workflow-power-pack-user.html).

Comment: unfortunately, this is the only way to do it. I had to intercept  during the synchronous call (ItemAdding and ItemUpdating method) and cancel the event